# What to do if the stock you brought are stopped trading

Tags: india

I brought 100 VBIND Stocks and stopped trading since 7th Aug 2018. The
Stock is also not showing under zerodha profile holdings. When I look into q.zerodha.com it is showing as NA. 
  How to get at least my holding back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Indian regulator (SEBI) has banned trading in 300 shell companies that it views as being "Shady", including VB Industries.

According to [Money Control (.com)](http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/markets-business/the-bull-market-fools-theory-shell-companies-rose-up-to-200-in-2017-2354689.html):

> all these shady companies have started to rally and there was a complaint to SEBI that investors are getting SMSs from various brokerage firms to invest in them

This suggests evidence of "pump and dump" style stock promotion.

On the plus side, the SEBI will permit trading in these securities once a month :

> Trading in these securities shall be permitted once a month (First Monday of the month). Further, any upward price movement in these securities shall not be permitted beyond the last traded price and additional surveillance deposit of 200 percent of trade value shall be collected form the Buyers which shall be retained with Exchanges for a period of five months.

This will give you an opportunity to exit your position, however, finding a buyer may be a problem and because of the severe restrictions placed on trading, any bid prices in the market are going to be a fraction of the last trade price.